# I need help on getting this loop to work as it should?

Tags: python

I'm needing help on getting the loop in my function Deductions to work.

I've tried looking through similar problems on stackoverflow but struggling to get my head around them.

```
def Deductions(money, Tax, TotalInsurance):

    deductions = 0
    global TotalDed
    TotalDed = 0
    choice = ""

    while not choice == "Y" or choice == "N":
        try:
            choice = str(input("Do you want to add any more deductions to your income, e.g car, rent or mortgage? Y/N : "))

        except ValueError:

            print("Must enter Y or N")

        if choice == "Y":

            while choice == "Y":

                AddDed = int(input("How much would you like to deduct: "))

                deductions = AddDed + deductions

                loop = str(input("Would you like to add more deductions? Y/N: "))

            if loop == "Y":
                choice == "Y"

            elif loop == "N":

                choice =="N"

        elif choice == "N":

            TotalDed = TotalTax + deductions


    print("Income: £", money)
    print("Taxed: £", Tax)
    print("National Insurance: £", TotalInsurance)
    print("Other Deductions: £", deductions)
    print("Total Deductions: £", TotalDed)

    return TotalDed
```

I'm wanting to make sure that my loop only accepts "Y" and "N". then to proceed to ask for Deductions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: `not choice == "Y" or choice == "N"` is equivalent to `(not choice == "Y") or (choice == "N")`. `or` has a higher precedence than `not`. Try `choice not in ('Y', 'N')` instead.

Answer (score 0):

### I think there are several mistakes in your code :

As pointed out in the comments, from what I understand that you're trying to do, you should use `while not (choice == "Y" or choice == "N")`.

You seem to have forgotten `TotalTax = Tax + TotalInsurance`.

`try/except` will not throw out a `ValueError`from input, so what you're looking for is probably an `else` clause after `if` and `elif`.

`choice == "Y"` is a boolean, it does not set a value. You're looking for `choice = "Y"`.

I think you're confused when you're using the `choice` variable in a second `while` loop and then use `loop` to set a value to `choice`. Below is another structure I would choose for what you're trying to do.

You can also add more protection against the possible wrong values from `input` statements.

To sum this up, here is what I think you should write :

```
def Deductions(money, Tax, TotalInsurance):

    deductions = 0
    global TotalDed
    TotalDed = 0
    TotalTax = Tax + TotalInsurance
    choice = ""

    while choice != "N":
        choice = input("Do you want to add any more deductions to your income, e.g car, rent or mortgage? Y/N : ")

        if choice == "Y":
            AddDed = float(input("How much would you like to deduct: "))
            deductions = AddDed + deductions

        elif choice != "N":
            print("Must enter Y or N")

    TotalDed = TotalTax + deductions
    print("Income: £", money)
    print("Taxed: £", Tax)
    print("National Insurance: £", TotalInsurance)
    print("Other Deductions: £", deductions)
    print("Total Deductions: £", TotalDed)

    return TotalDed
```

Also

```
AddDed = float(input("How much would you like to deduct: "))
deductions = AddDed + deductions
```

can be replaced with

```
valid_added_value = False
while not valid_added_value:
    try:
        AddDed = float(input("How much would you like to deduct: "))
        valid_added_value = True
    except ValueError:
        print('Must be a numerical value')
deductions = AddDed + deductions
```

for extra protection, because it could throw a `ValueError`.

Also you don't need `str` in front of `input` because `input` already returns a `str` object in python3.

I'm not sure either why you need `global TotalDed` since you already return it but maybe you have a good reason.